# WebRTC samples fail on Chrome and Firefox when running locally

Tags: windows, webrtc, p2p, sample

When trying out the WebRTC sample where video is streamed to a peer connection:

https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/capture/video-pc

In Firefox, I see only a black video rendered on the right video :-(

In Chrome I encounter a cross-origins error:
    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Cannot capture from element with cross-origin data
        at HTMLVideoElement.maybeCreateStream

I have made no code changes, I simply cloned the repo and opened the index.html. I also tried serving the pages without luck in seeing the video.

How can I run this sample locally on Windows using either Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I run this sample locally on Windows using either Chrome or
>   Firefox?

The code base contains a server.js file under web_server folder. You can run it locally using nodejs.

- Make sure you have nodejs, and npm installed.
- Run `npm install` from the base directory to install the
  dependencies.
- Goto web_server folder, and run the server.js file using 
  `node server.js`
- It should start the server, and the sample(s) will be available at
  https://localhost:8080

You should be able to access your demo https://localhost:8080/src/content/capture/video-pc/

The demo runs in my machine. You have not mentioned which browser version you are using. 
I used `Chrome : Version 75.0.3770.100` for testing.

Comment: Ah - the issue was I was not running the server from the root, thanks!

Comment: Wondering why the 'servers' parameter is able to be null in this sample.
I'd like to run this sample on two different browser instances ideally on two different machines. 
In this case - I assume there should only be a single RTCPeerConnection per browser.

Comment: I am afraid, the 'servers' parameter in [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection) is not actually the express, or other web server parameter. It actually a `RTCConfiguration dictionary`.

Comment: Given samples is a loopback peer connection example, and designed to work locally. Here, express server was used just to server the static files. But, you can extend this sample application and can run it in two different machines. You will be needing a Signaling server to exchange your ICE, and SDP between peers in your different machines.